# Java Script overwriting array indices after splicing

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io, alias, phaser-framework

I'm having an issue where it seems like I'm overwriting array indices after splicing, at least I think. Its for a little game being built using phaser 2. Its essentially just a little multiplayer jumping game to get some experience with client / server architecture. Were using socket.io and express. My problem seems to be on the server where when a client disconnects, when its removed from the list of players, the other player still in the game seems to overwrite the index of the player who disconnected. For debugging this I've mostly been using console logs, using a for loop to iterate over the list and print out player's socket IDs. So for example, if I player 1 with socket ID 1 joins, then player 2 with socket id 2 joins, then player 2 leaves, the for loop would print out 1, 1. If a new player 3 with socket id 3 joins after player 2 had left, printing out the ID's of the players would print out 1, 1, 3. At first I thought the issue was that in the onNewPlayer(data) function, that I had an aliasing problem because I was using var currentInfo in two different places, so I changed the second object to be var info. Does it seem like this is an aliasing issue of some sort, or should I be searching somewhere else for this issue? I can supply additional code if required, so far all our callbacks for player creation and movement have been working fine. Thanks.

below is the relevant server side code

```
var players[];
//When a new player is made, save it
function onNewPlayer(data) {
  var newPlayer = new Player(data.x, data.y, this.id);

  var currentInfo = {
    x: newPlayer.x,
    y: newPlayer.y,
    id: newPlayer.id,
  };

  for(i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    //broadcast the new player out to all the other players in the list  
    this.broadcast.emit("newEnemy", currentInfo);
  }

  //check for if there are already players,
  //if so, send the player's who are already in the game to the new player
  if(players.length > 0) {
    for(i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        var info = {
            x: players[i].x,
            y: players[i].y,
            id: players[i].id,
        };
        this.emit("newEnemy", info);
    }
  }

  players.push(newPlayer);
  for(i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    console.log(players[i].id);
  }
}

function onDisconnect(){
    console.log("User " + this.id + " disconnected");
    //find the user in the list of players and remove them, then tell the client
    for(i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if(players[i].id === this.id) {
            console.log("removing this player " + this.id);
            //TODO trying a different broadcast
            this.broadcast.emit("playerDisconnect", this.id);
            console.log(players[i].id);
            players.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

below is the relevant client side code

```
//We've lost connection with the server!
function onSocketDisconnect() {
    console.log("Lost connection with server!");
};

//When the server notifies the client an enemy has disconnected,
//search for it in the enemies list and stop rendering it
function onEnemyDisconnect(data) {
    //TODO
    for(i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
        if(enemies[i].id == data) {
            //TODO
            console.log("destroying");
            enemies[i].destroy();
            enemies.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating an array in the forward direction with a `for` loop AND removing elements from the array with `.splice()`.  That will not work properly because when you call `.splice()` to remove an item from the array, it copies down the later elements from the array down one position.  But, your `for` loop index is pointing to the next element in the array.  The end-result is that you skip iterating items in the array.

There are multiple possible solutions.

1. You can iterate the array backwards instead of forwards.  When iterating in reverse order, the elements you have not yet iterated are not affected by your `.splice()` and it works just fine.
2. You can stop modifying the array while in the `for` loop.  Perhaps you collect a set of indexes you want to remove and then remove them from back to front afterwards.
3. You can use `.filter()` to create a new array that is a subset of the original array and when done with the `.filter()` operation just assign the new array to your variable and use it from then on.
4. You can keep the iteration the way you are, but correct the `for` loop index after you call `.splice()` by decrementing it by one.

Here's an example of the reverse array iteration:

```
// When the server notifies the client an enemy has disconnected,
// search for it in the enemies list and stop rendering it
function onEnemyDisconnect(data) {
    // use reverse iteration to avoid skipping elements when calling .splice()
    for (i = enemies.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        if(enemies[i].id == data) {
            console.log("destroying");
            enemies[i].destroy();
            enemies.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's an example of `.filter()` that assumes you can assign to `enemies` and the new array will permanently take its place:

```
// When the server notifies the client an enemy has disconnected,
// search for it in the enemies list and stop rendering it
function onEnemyDisconnect(data) {
    enemies = enemies.filter(item => {
        if (item.id === data) {
            console.log("destroying");
            item.destroy();
            return false;    // don't keep this one
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I never would have found that. Still really new to JS, coming from C/C++.  I ended up just copying the index and removing the desired object after the for loop ended.

Comment: @user406955 - If there's only ever one match, you can just `break` your `for` loop after you do the `.splice()` and there should be no issue.  These solutions are for when you can have more than one match.

Comment: I should only have to handle removing one player at a time, I think with the callbacks it should only get called for the single socket that disconnected right?